# CAN message read error

Tags: microcontroller, can-bus

I am using the [Infineon XC2768X](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontrollers/development-tools-software-and-kits/xc2000-development-tools-software-and-kits/starterkits-and-evaluation-boards/starter-kit-xc2768x/channel.html?channel=db3a30432ba3fa6f012be87234f40dc9) [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller). The problem is at the line with the `if` statement. 'uwspeed' is the speed of motor I am receiving from the external CAN Bus. When the code reaches this line, it doesn't turn on the [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) P10_6 and P10_7. How can I fix this problem?

```
void read_Motorspeed () {
    stCAN_SWObj SW_obj1;
    ubyte i;
    ADC0_vStartSeq0ReqChNum(0,0,0,0);
    uwbesch = ADC0_uwGetResultData(RESULT_REG_0); //Read gaspedal
    CAN_vReleaseObj(1);
    CAN_vGetMsgObj(1, &SW_obj1);
    uwspeed1 = SW_obj1.ubData[0]; //Receiving high byte
    uwspeed2 = SW_obj1.ubData[1]; //Receiving low byte
    IO_vSetPin(IO_P10_8);         //Initially motor is series connected by pin 10.8

    if((uwspeed1 < 0x0b && IO_P10_8 == 1)) { //If the speed is less than 0x0b and series connected
        IO_vResetPin(IO_P10_8); //Disconnect series
        IO_vSetPin(IO_P10_6);   //Here pin 10.6 is on
        IO_vSetPin(IO_P10_7);   //Here pin 10.7 is on
        CAN_MODATA3LL = 0x00;   //Send 0 torque to hybrid kit
        CAN_vTransmit(3);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure of the endianness of the CAN bus? (Are high and low bytes in the right order?)  Why are you setting Pin 10.8 then immediately checking it in the conditional?  Also consider parenthesising compound conditionals (if((uwspeed1 < 0x0b) && (IO_P10_8)) so the precedence is easier to follow.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply!Actually the switching-on of the Pin 10.8 is not mandatory here but i just switched it on so that the Motor runs first in series and then I want to check it if it is series and with the speed limit.I output one of the result on Port 10,that worked.but when i compare any one of it to 0x0b and IO_P10_8,then the pin 10.6 and 10.7 don't work.